# Loop insert SQL query

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have the below query which returns 400 million rows. I want to run the query so it loops through and inserts 1 million records at a time. Please can I get the loop query.

```
insert into AST (DataAreaId, Name)

select f.DataAreaId, its.Name....... etc
from Transform.InventFin f
inner join Staging.INVENTSETTLEMENT its
on f.ITSRECID=its.RECID
and f.DataAreaId=its.DATAAREAID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following(Assuming that `DataAreaId` is Unique, if not you need to include those columns in `NOT EXISTS`).

```
declare @Count int
set @Count = 1
while @Count > 0
   begin
         insert into AST (DataAreaId, Name)
        select TOP (1000000)  f.DataAreaId, its.Name....... etc
        from Transform.InventFin f
        inner join Staging.INVENTSETTLEMENT its
        on f.ITSRECID=its.RECID
        and f.DataAreaId=its.DATAAREAID 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
         SELECT 1 FROM AST A WHERE AST.DataAreaId = F.DataAreaId
        )
     set @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
   end
```

Comment: DataAreaID isn't the primary key so will this still apply?

Comment: You need to make it unique to avoid any duplicates, for this you will be required to add the condition to your  to WHERE AST.DataAreaId = F.DataAreaId and AST.Col1= tbl.Col1 AND AST.Col2=tbl.Col2. like this